# Criteria fetch @ManyToOne relationship partially

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Is there a way to fetch an associated `ManyToOne` associated entity partially only using criteria?

I have the following case

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Bar bar;
    // getters/setters and lots other attributes
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<ComplexObject> complexObjects;
    // getters/setters
}
```

And I have a `Criteria` that selects all my `Foo`'s and I want fetch together with it only the `name` of the  `Bar` associated to it. I don't want the collection of `ComplexObject`s to be loaded together. Is there a way to accomplish that without modifying `Bar`?

I want this because I want to show to the user something like

```
      Foo.Attr1, Foo.Attr2, Foo.Bar.Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's impossible. When you mark a collection as eagrely fetched, it's always eagerly fetched. If you want it lazily loaded, it should be marked lazy.

But you may select only your three attributes:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Foo.class, "foo");
c.createAlias("foo.bar", "bar");
c.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("foo.attr1"))
                                            .add(Projections.property("foo.attr2"))
                                            .add(Projections.property("bar.name")));
```

Or, much more readable:

```
String hql = "select foo.attr1, foo.attr2, bar.name from Foo foo"
             + " inner join foo.bar bar";
```

Comment: The part about not letting the collection being lazy collected I knew. But you answered my question :) It's this projection I need.

Comment: Is there a way to make Hibernate map this projection list to Foo?

Comment: There is a way, using a ResultTransformer, but it's extremely dirty. A method which returns entity instances should return entity instances, respecting their invariants and contracts, attached to the session, etc. Not some half-populated objects.

Comment: Yes, that's a fact. Thanks for the help :D